# Migrate to NetSuite SDF SuiteApp

Tags: netsuite

I have an existing SuiteBundle (non-SDF SuiteApp) that has been installed into multiple accounts. How can that bundle be converted into a SDF SuiteApp without creating a new bundle?

From what I've seen so far, it seems like the only option is to stand up a mirror copy of the existing configurations (associated to the SDF SuiteApp Id) and create a new bundle. This would lead to a very messy upgrade process for customers.

Answer (score 0):

You can depreciate the old bundle with the creation of the new one.

Comment: Thanks, depreciation seems like the correct path, but doesn't that require the new bundle to be copied from the old bundle? Since the option to choose a SDF SuiteApp project only appears when creating a new bundle (not coping/editing), I don't know how to make this work.

Comment: Ever get an answer to this flow?